# Reduce Datastore Write Operations

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, web-crawler

I am building a web-crawler on Google App Engine. To store the crawled information in Data Store, I am using the following field using JDO. The Code is as follows:

```
public class LinkInfo
{
   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent private String id;

   @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
   @Persistent private int linkNo;

   @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
   @Persistent private String link;

   @Persistent private int version;

   @Persistent private String fetchDate;

   @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
   @Persistent private long fetchTime;

   @Persistent private String nextFetch;

   @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
   @Persistent private String pageCreationDate;

   @Persistent private int retries;

   @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
   @Persistent private int retryInterval;

   @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
   @Persistent private int outLinks;

   @Persistent private float score;

   @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
   @Persistent private String abstractContent;

   @Persistent private String contentType;

   @Persistent private String parent;

   @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
   @Persistent private String title;

       ...
```

Out of the 16 fields, I have made 8 undindexed because I don't need to filter or Sort them. Even now, I am exceeding the Datastore Write Operation limit.

Any Suggestions to reduce by "Datastore Write Operations" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much you can do to reduce writes... assuming you're not updating the data very often. It's reads that you can optimize through caching. Based on your example this is a pretty straight forward table, no joins, so if you're just storing data in there, not much you can do. Are you seeing more than a couple of writes per entry when you save the data?

The only thing I would suggest is ditching JDO completely and just writing to the datastore through the native API to really optimize your writes if JDO is taking more than a couple of operations to persist an object, but really, it shouldn't be much worse than you could do yourself.

Comment: I am seeing almost 2500 operations for approx 80 entries. Do JDO & native API code have difference in no of write operations? I would like to know more about it. But I agree Native API is faster then JDO, while JDO is more easy to use, according to this discussion [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/3rVcmKc7iI4)

Comment: The native API is much faster in terms of minimizing calls. You might want to look at objectify which is much closer to the native layer and IMHO easier than jdo

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try using Native API, hope that will work.

Comment: Thanks, Using Native API, results are pretty fast than JDO. But number of write operations remained almost the same.

Comment: Do you know if the writes are for the indexes? Do you have any extra indexes defined in your index file?

Comment: No extra indexes have been defined in the Index File.

Comment: where do you see the number of operations? Because via appstats I can see only the datastore_v3.Put calls. But not the real operations to the indexes and to the datastore

Answer (score 7):

From Google App Engine:

For each new Entity Put:

> "2 writes + 2 writes per indexed property value + 1 write per composite index value."

So, for every one entity, you will have 2+2*8+ (however many custom indexes you have).

This is a minimum of 18 per entity.

**The best way to reduce write count is to reduce the number of indexed properties.**